# Facebook instant articles not pulling in full RSS and keeps saying there's less than 10 articles

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

We have a RSS feed URL set up for FB Instant Articles to read from:

http://www.southafrica.net/blog/en/posts/facebook
I've copied the contents of this response to this pastebin in case the content changes in future: http://pastebin.com/38aGNtah

This feed has thousands of articles, although the feed is limited to 20 items.

Even though this URL is configured as the Production RSS feed on the Instant Articles configuration page, it still says:

Not Enough Articles
You must create 10 or more articles in your Production library before submitting for review.

Image for reference:
[image: Screenshot]

Can somebody please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: On a side note (not sure if it is the actual issue), your markup is invalid. It is missing the header, footer, canonical URL etc. Here is an example of how it should look like https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/guides/articlecreate#sample-article

Comment: I'm having the same issue despite having all the correct markup.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to claim the url that you will be pulling rss feed from. After that you need to check on Styles. If you don't have a logo uploaded already, I noticed that FB task ignores that article feed. If you successfully claimed your url and added style with a logo they all should appear on your list.

Comment: hi, I need your help, Can you help me?